# What does "Ой всё" mean?

Tags: перевод, значения, сленг, meme

What does "Ой всё" mean? My Russian friends use it a lot.

Comment: Wery often adding some examples would make answers more helpful. Questions about language usually have different answers depending on context.

Comment: Phrase came from popular russian meme. Before "memoizing" this
phrase was not so popular.

Comment: Виктор, а вы же сами носитель русского языка?

Comment: @shabunc да. Но не думаю, что это повод меня минусовать.

Comment: минусовать может любой пользователь не понравившиеся вопросы, задавать вопросы на которые очевидно вы знаете ответ - вообще-то это тоже по правилам и стопроцентно приемлемый кейс. Я просто не совсем догнал - как говорят мои русские друзья - чего это - так они тоже говорят - за закос под иностранца :P А если серьёзно, то понимание является ли автор вопроса носителем языка или нет иногда помогает дать более полезный и полный ответ.

Comment: It is more, like: "whatever!".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**"Ой, все"** - it is a very informal way to stop discussion. It is mostly used by women as a final argument in a dispute.

Women always want to say the "last word" in any dispute but if they feel they don't have any more agruments they can say **"Ой, все"** and can even leave the room-)))

If you hear **"Ой, все"** it usially means that you are right.

Answer (score 17):

This expression means something along the lines of "I'm done", meaning that someone is not willing to continue an argument. Quite often it implies that a person saying "Oй все" lost an argument. The phrase can also be used as a joke to mock such behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

'Ohh, that's all.' literally.

It means like you don't wanna chat, you wanna change a topic of the speech or dialogue. Sometimes it means that opponent don't wanna think about this problem/task right now, because he/she can't see solution or does not agree with your solution/thoughts. Yes, sometimes it can be translated as 'Lets stop talking, I STILL don't agree with you. There is no point in our dialogue/You are hopeless.' Also "ой, всё" can be used as a joke, not seriously.

Comment: It's also used a lot to make fun of female logic. Especially like a last argument in discussion that can't be beaten.

Answer (score 1):

are everybody sure they get the meaning of the phrase right?

i can envision two meanings

**А**

> Enough of that!

to cut the conversation short

**B**

> Wow, is that right?

a sarcastic remark meant to belittle the significance of the interlocutor's statement

in this sense the phrase can also look like

> Ой (ну теперь) всё!

`всё` in the sense of `всё пропало`

synonymous to such sarcastic phrases as

> Ой, горе-то какое!
>   Ой, что ж теперь делать?
>   Ой, как жить-то теперь?

Answer (score 0):

It is used as an indication that something happened or broke unexpectedly. In an overly cute and helpless sort of way. Kind of like "oopsie!"

Comment: I suppose, it would be simply "ой".

Comment: It's more about  "ну, всё [приехали]", "ой всё" is a slightly different thing